# Why are some JavaScript variables accessed by placing a 0 right after the variable name?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say you have an object literal:

```
var d = {
    x: +'35',
    y: '25'
};
```

And an anonymous function:

```
function (d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
}
```

When I experiment with this code, I get "undefined" in place of d.y0. But there is plenty of d3.js code that accesses a value by appending 0 to its key. What does this 0 do?

Comment: It doesn't do anything unless other code in d3 has created such variables or object properties. In other words, it's definitely not a language feature.

Comment: please show the code that you are referring to.

Comment: Okay, it's clear to me that d.y0 is NOT a language feature. As request, here's the link to the code: http://bl.ocks.org/1134768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `d.y0` is undefined unless `d` has a property named `y0`. I'm not familiar with d3 but if it uses pure JavaScript then the only way they can reference properties with an appended 0 is if the objects from which they're referencing the properties have a property with that name.

Comment: But what bothers me is that the example shown here: http://bl.ocks.org/1134768 uses d.y0 twice, when d.y0 was never defined. It's hard for me to make out what it's supposed to do. Removing the 0 on the two occurrences completely ruins the chart.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the javascript source from your link, y0 is an internal designation used in d3 to refer to the y coordinate of the first point in your collection of data, e.g.:

```
function d3_svg_lineBundle(points, tension) {
  var n = points.length - 1;
  if (n) {
    var x0 = points[0][0],
        // Here
        y0 = points[0][1],
```

or

```
function d3_svg_lineBasis(points) {
  if (points.length < 3) return d3_svg_lineLinear(points);
  var i = 1,
      n = points.length,
      pi = points[0],
      x0 = pi[0],
      // Here
      y0 = pi[1],
```

There's definitely nothing special about appending '0' to property names!

Code samples are from this js file: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.29.1